# Get values from an html Table cell with php

Tags: php, html, split, preg-match, preg-split

How can I get the values in bold from the next string?

```
<td>26/02/2015</td><td>09:00</td><td>26/02/2015</td><td>12:00</td><td>3</td><td>I1/121</td><td>10074 codification</td><td>103126 Codification, Cooperation and development - 11</td><td>**Walter** Shelter, Mary; **Johnson** Smith, Robert; **Dickinson** Queen, Patty</td><td>without group</td>
```

Taking into account the values I want to get may be more or less. For example, the values between < td > and < /td > can be:

**Walter** Shelter, Mary; **Johnson** Smith, Robert; **Dickinson** Queen, Patty; **More** Values, John; **AndMore** Values, Alfred;

Or

**Less** Values, John; **AndLess** Values, Alfred;

I'm trying with regex, preg_split, preg_match, implode, explode and can't figure it out. Thanks!

**EDIT: This is what I'm trying.**

```
$myMatches = array();


          if(preg_match_all("~\<td\>{9}(.+?)\<\/td\>~",$filtered,$mat)){
                foreach($mat[1] as $match){
                  $myMatches[] = htmlentities($match);
                  }

          }
        foreach ($myMatches as $m){

        echo $m;

        }
```

Comment: you can also use regex and find everything between 2 html tags

Comment: why aren't you using javascript (jQuery) to find these specific elements?

Comment: @Fadey , Ghost and floor, Thanks a lot for your response! Is javascript or regex necessary? I've been struggling with regex.

Comment: [Don't parse HTML with RegEx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), do a search for "PHP HTML parser".

Comment: if you use jQuery you wont have to use regex. that's what's jquery is all about, querying the DOM